# Controller responds to AJAX request with entire view

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have a login form (in **index.jsp**) which is submitted by jQuery's POST function to my controller. Once the submit button is clicked, the entire view is loaded into my error-message element - rather than the username entered into the form input.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

**Login form**

```
<form class="form-inline" id="loginForm" role="form" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username"
            autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password"
            autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="loginBtn" class="btn btn-default" id="loginBtn">Log in</button>
    </div>
        <label class="formErrorMsg" id="loginErrorMsg" for="loginBtn"></label>
</form>
```

**login.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check that the login credentials entered are valid
    $("#loginBtn").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("/login", {username : $("#username").val()}, function(result){
            $("#loginErrorMsg").html(result)
        });
    });
});
```

**indexController**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {
    // Map requests for "/" to index.jsp
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView returnIndexPage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        return model;
    }
    // Map AJAX request, via login form, to login
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String checkLoginCredentials(@RequestParam("username") String username){
        return username;
    }
}
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>

    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the inline form field validation, you need to add `<form:errors` for each field in the html `form` to be validated and displayed with an error message.

Also, you need to validate the data with `@Valid` or custom validator in the controller method to return all the errors from the form and you can look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/) or [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) for a simple examples.